# JavaScript Map, Filter, redule, forEach does not change the original array. right?

Tags: javascript

I have been using these array function and know that these does not change the original array. correct me if I am wrong.

And these function does not work on object.

Is there anything available in javascript which will change the original array. I know the work around is

`arr = arr.map((val, index)=>{// change value here}); // I dont want to assign the aray it shelf`

## I want something like

`arr.map((val, index)=>{// change value here}); // it should change the original array`

Comment: `arr.forEach((val, index) => arr[index] = ...)`

Answer (score 1):

None of those methods have side effects to each element since everything in JavaScript is passed by value. You can modify the items themselves, just not what is referenced in the array.

If you really want to change the original array, a traditional `for` loop can do that or just use the `index` argument provided.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
  if (shouldReplace(i)) {
     arr[i] = newValue(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not willing to re-assign the variable as you mentioned, and you are not adding or removing elements, then your best bet is:

```
arr.forEach((val, index)=>{val.foo = bar;});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` callback method accepts a third parameter which is the original array. So you could technically do something like this:

```js
var arr = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grape'];

arr.map((item, idx, org) => org[idx] = '1 ' + item);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: why use map - that creates an unused array.

Comment: does it work for all others like filter, reduce, forEach ?

Comment: @AniruddhaDas those each iterate the whole collection and they have their own specific usecase.

Comment: @DanielA.White A valid argument - however, does not answer the OP's question of how to use map. Agreed, not optimal, but correct nonetheless.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas - Yes, the prototype methods you mentioned each reference the original array in the callback. Note that it's the fourth parameter in `reduce`.

Comment: Got it. I was looking more straight forward but your answer managed some way with the original array. I saw that in manual but totally ignored it. I agree with your answer. Still I will keep open this question to see if there is more elegant way to do this :)